# Java/Scala remote HDFS usage

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to connect to remote HDFS cluster. I've read some documentation and getting started's but didn't find a best solution how to do that.
Situation: I have HDFS on xxx-something.com. I can connect to it via SSH and everything works.

But what I'm trying to do, get the files from it to my local machine.

What I've done:

I've created core-site.xml in my conf folder (I'm creating Play! application). There I've changed fs.default.name config to hdfs://xxx-something.com:8020 (not sure about the port).
Then I'm trying to launch a simple test:

```
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.addResource(new Path("conf/core-site.xml"))
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/data/"))
```

And I'm getting errors:

```
 13:56:09.012 [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - conf/core-site.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: fs.trash.interval;  Ignoring.
13:56:09.012 [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - conf/core-site.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: hadoop.tmp.dir;  Ignoring.
13:56:09.013 [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - conf/core-site.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: fs.checkpoint.dir;  Ignoring.
13:56:09.022 [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem - Creating filesystem for hdfs://xxx-something.com:8021
13:56:09.059 [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - java.io.IOException: config()
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.<clinit>(SecurityUtil.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.<clinit>(NetUtils.java:62)
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:
probably the port was wrong. Now I set it to 22, I'm still getting same errors, but after 3 times it does say:

```
14:01:01.877 [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Connecting to xxx-something.com/someIp:22
14:01:02.187 [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47) connection to xxx-something.com/someIp:22 from britva sending #0
14:01:02.188 [IPC Client (47) connection to xxx-something.com/someIp:22 from britva] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47) connection to xxx-something.com/someIp:22 from britva: starting, having connections 1
14:01:02.422 [IPC Client (47) connection to xxx-something.com/someIp:22 from britva] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47) connection to xxx-something.com/someIp:22 from britva got value #1397966893
```

And afterwards:

```
Call to xxx-something.com/someIp:22 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
java.io.IOException: Call to xxx-something.com/someIp:22 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:122)
    at HdfsSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(HdfsSpec.scala:33)
    at HdfsSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(HdfsSpec.scala:17)
    at testingSupport.specs2.MyNotifierRunner$$anon$2$$anon$1.executeBody(MyNotifierRunner.scala:16)
    at testingSupport.specs2.MyNotifierRunner$$anon$2$$anon$1.execute(MyNotifierRunner.scala:16)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:745)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to find the fs.default.name property in the $HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml on the server running the Name Node (HDFS master) to get the correct port. It might be 8020, or it could be something else. That's what you should use. Make sure there's no firewall between you and the server that disallows connections on the port.